# mysql: convert timediff() to seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks something like the following:

`select timediff(time_end, time_begin) from tbl`

`time_end` and `time_begin` are both of type `datetime`

Is there a trivial way I can convert the time there to return an integer (seconds)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Mysql TIME_TO_SEC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) is what you are looking for

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time_end, time_begin)) from tbl
```