# How to show time difference over 24 hours between timestamps

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query that returns speed to response. It works correctly expect for instances when the timediff calculation results is over 24 hours. I get a error of "java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '31' for java.sal.Time type in value"

The number of '31' varies with the variance of hours between the timestamps.

I'm not sure where to precede from here. I tried timestampdiff() but get an error while trying to run the query.

Any comments or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(SELECT
databunker.purchases.id                                           AS 'pur_id',
 databunker.purchases.business                                    AS 'pur_business',
 databunker.purchases.time                                        AS 'pur_time',
 databunker.customers.id                                          AS 'customer_id',
 databunker.customers.phone_number                                AS 'customer_phone_#',
 databunker.customers.is_primary                                  AS 'customer_is_primary',
 map.object_salesforce_id,
 databunker.five9_calls.campaign_name,
 databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp AS 'start_of_call',
 TIMEDIFF(databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp, databunker.purchases.time) AS 'speed_to_response'

FROM databunker.purchases
 LEFT OUTER JOIN databunker.customers ON (databunker.purchases.customer_id = databunker.customers.id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                    databunker.mappings.object_salesforce_id,
                    databunker.mappings.object_id AS 'map_customer_id'
                  FROM databunker.mappings
                  WHERE databunker.mappings.object_class = 'customer') AS map
   ON (databunker.purchases.customer_id = map.map_customer_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN databunker.five9_calls ON (map.object_salesforce_id = 
databunker.five9_calls.salesforce_id)
WHERE databunker.purchases.business = 'uma'
     AND databunker.purchases.outcome_type = 'accepted'
     AND databunker.purchases.time >= curdate() - 1

     AND databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp >= databunker.purchases.time

GROUP BY
 databunker.purchases.id,
 databunker.purchases.business,
 databunker.purchases.time,
 databunker.customers.id,
 databunker.customers.phone_number,
 map.object_salesforce_id,
 databunker.five9_calls.campaign_name,
 databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp,
 TIMEDIFF(databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp, databunker.purchases.time)

 ORDER BY databunker.purchases.id, databunker.purchases.time, 
 databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp ASC) a

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT
  databunker.purchases.id AS 'pur_id_2',
  MIN(databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp) AS 'call_time'


FROM databunker.purchases
  LEFT OUTER JOIN databunker.customers ON (databunker.purchases.customer_id = databunker.customers.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                     databunker.mappings.object_salesforce_id,
                     databunker.mappings.object_id AS 'map_customer_id'
                   FROM databunker.mappings
                   WHERE databunker.mappings.object_class = 'customer') AS map
    ON (databunker.purchases.customer_id = map.map_customer_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN databunker.five9_calls ON (map.object_salesforce_id = databunker.five9_calls.salesforce_id)
WHERE databunker.purchases.business = 'uma'
      AND databunker.purchases.outcome_type = 'accepted'
      AND databunker.purchases.time >= curdate() - 1

      AND databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp >= databunker.purchases.time

GROUP BY
  databunker.purchases.id
) b

ON a.pur_id = b.pur_id_2 AND a.start_of_call = b.call_time
```

[image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and leave out anything not directly relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, preferably in text, not image.

Comment: Could you please add only timediff query with sample input and sample output, to study the whole query does not make any sense for this small problem.

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486954/mysql-convert-timediff-to-seconds

Answer (score 2):

There is "time of day" and there is "time span".

MySQL's `TIMEDIFF()` is returning a "time span" of 31 hours, etc.

Your Java code is expecting a "time of day" which, of course, should not be more than 23:59:59 (ignoring leap seconds).

One workaround is to say

```
TO_SECONDS(databunker.five9_calls.start_timestamp) -
TO_SECONDS(databunker.purchases.time)
```

but that won't return (for example) "31:58:47"; instead it will give "115127".

Another workaround is to avoid `java.sal.Time` and find a library that handles "time spans".